# Why does [ a -gt b ] (not [ "$a" -gt "$b" ]) appear to work?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have one problem in unix shell scripting. Let me ask you with very simple example.

suppose, I am getting user input and comparing two numbers.

```
echo "Enter the first number"
read a
echo "Enter the second number"
read b
if [ a -gt b ]---------------------->I have not used $ before variable name.
then
    echo "a is greater"
else
    echo "b is greater"
fi
```

In this example, i should have used $ to get the value of variable. By mistake, I forgot. Still, it gives me right result, how and why?

I tried to debug by using sh -x filename. but, it doesn't show any value while comparing(because i havn't used $ sign).

How the shell decide which is greater and vice versa? 
How it works internally?

Thanks.

Comment: It's comparing the character *a* against the character *b*

Comment: @Michael-you are saying, it compares character a against the character b. but, on what basis(ascii value or anything else)? Also, If it is comparing character a against character b then it should give same result everytime. But, it is giving me right result for both the cases.

Comment: Which shell are you testing on? As I show in my answer, the implementation of `test` bundled with bash treats this as an error.

Comment: The answer does a much better job of explaining than I can.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is usually linked to another shell; what does `ls -l /bin/sh` say?

Comment: @Vicky Which `/bin/sh`? Is it bash in compatibility mode? dash? ash?

Comment: Thanks Michael and Charles for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notably, you *could* use this without a `$` if you did the comparison in a numeric context.

In bash:

```
if (( a > b )); then
  echo "a is greater"
else
  echo "b is greater"
fi
```

...would be correct, as `(( ))` (double parens) enters a numeric context within which all textual strings are treated as variables and automatically dereferenced (and within which operators such as `>` and `<` have their typical arithmetic meanings, rather than performing redirections).

What you're doing now is heavily implementation-dependent. `[ a '>' b ]` would be a lexographic comparison between the letters `a` and `b`. `[ a -gt b ]` is an arithmetic test.

Many shells will not allow this at all. For instance:

```
$ a=2; b=3; [ a -gt b ]; echo $?
-bash: [: a: integer expression expected
2
```

Notably, this is different inside of bash's `[[ ]]` test context (which doesn't carry the POSIX semantics of `[ ]`). There, what you're doing actually *does* work, though it's harder to read than the `(( ))` form:

```
$ a=2; b=3; [[ a -gt b ]]; echo $?
1
$ a=3; b=2; [[ a -gt b ]]; echo $?
0
```

If you're limited to POSIX sh, you don't have `(( ))`, but you *do* have `$(( ))`, which you can use almost the same way:

```
$ a=2; b=3; result=$(( a > b ? 1 : 0 )); echo "$result"
0
$ a=3; b=2; result=$(( a > b ? 1 : 0 )); echo "$result"
1
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple explanation why your test appears to work: it blindly executes the `else` clause.

The `[ ... ]` built-in has no way to report the error to the caller except by exiting with a non-zero exit status. Incidentally, a non-zero exit status is also used to indicate "false". This means that `if` cannot distinguish between a false and an erroneous evaluation of its condition, which is why your comparison always prefers the `else` branch and thus appears to work. You can easily test it by reverting the arguments:

```
$ if [ b -gt a ]
then
    echo "b is greater"
else
    echo "a is greater"
fi
dash: 11: [: Illegal number: b
a is greater
```

Note that the error message printed to standard error is, as far as the `if` statement is concerned, a mere side effect of the test command, and is entirely ignored.

Comment: This is what's really going on, but @Charles's answer has lots of useful information as well.